# Amending a list based on index and dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime

I have start and end times for 2 pieces of data... Each start and end time represents a particular 'type' of event. I want to sort my data to the point where I have all the data joined together and sorted in date order and has as table in the form of below

Event       Start     End
...         ...       ...

```
start_event_A = [(i[:14], 'Event A Start') for i in start_event_A_list]
end_event_A = [(i[:14], 'Event A End') for i in end_event_A_list]
```

`start_event_B = [(i[:14], 'Event B Start') for i in start_event_B_list]
 end_event_B = [(i[:14], 'Event A End') for i in end_event_B_list]`

```
dates = start_event_A + start_event_B

dates_l = [(datetime.strptime(d, '%d%b%y %H%M%S'), l) for d, l in dates]
```

`dates_l.sort()`

This gives me a list of start times, combining events A and B in order. I want to give each event it's corresponding end time by looking up their respective lists and appending to the correct start time 'line'

I'm not so sure how to go about it. Or even if the way I've done it so far is the best way of my set objective.

my input list data (start_event_A_list) is of the form:

```
[('15MAR18 121203', 'Event Start A'), ('15MAR18 134443', 'Event Start A'), ('Event Start A', 'Event Start A'),
```

same format for the other lists too

Any help appreciated

Comment: Can you provide some representative data, please? We can't see `start_event_A_list` and `start_event_B_list`, for example. In addition, what is your desired output?

Comment: The start_event_A_list and end lists are of the form '18JAN18 Event A Start' etc...  The output I need is a combined events in date order with the start and end times of each event in the same line

Comment: Excellent, Can you please update your post with *5 lines of such data formatted appropriately so we can use in code*?

Comment: OK. I'm afraid this isn't sufficient for me to understand *what exactly what you want* in your dataframe and in what format. Please rewrite your question so it is more clear. Good luck!